# How to launch ajax function based on a condition in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to launch an ajax call based **on a** **condition** (folder not empty) .

The result of my condition is working fine in php file **check_file.php**

Here is my **check_file.php** how it looks like

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST["folder"])) 
{
$dir = $_POST['folder'];
$files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..'));
$result;

if (!is_dir_empty($dir) && trim(substr( json_encode($files), 6, 2 )) == 'ok'  )  
{ 
$result = 0;  
}
else  {$result = 1;}

echo $result;
unlink($dir.'/'.trim($files[2])  )  ; 
}

function is_dir_empty($dir) {
if (!is_readable($dir)) return null; 
return (count(scandir($dir)) == 2);
}
?>
```

In my JavaScript script this is how it looks like

```
function downloadExcel() {
// Mu folder path 
var folder="D:/output";
if (result.isConfirmed) {
               $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'check_file.php',
                    data: {
                        folder: folder
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(result){
                        if(result==0)
                        {
                            Swal.fire(
                                    'Execution  success , please check your email '
                            );
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Swal.fire(
                                'Execution  en cours   '
                            );  
                        }
                        
                },
            error: function(result){

               console.log("Error request Ajax");
            } 
            });
            
            refresh();

        } else 
            result.dismiss === Swal.DismissReason.cancel
        }
```

I'm new to javascript , how could i test if folder is not empty launch the $.Ajax  call

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking since you would probably need to make an ajax request to find out if folder contains anything so this sounds like chicken before the egg

Comment: In my file check_file.php i'm already checken that using this function is_dir_empty